# function call with this keyword is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am calling local (class) function via `this` pointer, but get an error `'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function'`. Probem occur on line 
`this.createtimetable();` at `loadtimetable` function.

My JS (relevant) is :

```
this.createtimetable = function () {
    this.inside_timetable = [];
    for (var d = new Date(in_week_start); d <= new Date(in_week_end); d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {
        console.log(new Date(d));
        daysOfYear.push(new Date(d));
    }
}

this.loadtimetable = function (in_guide_id, in_week_start, in_week_end) {
    this.guide_id = in_guide_id;
    this.week_start = in_week_start;
    this.week_end = in_week_end;
    $.post("./j.php", {
        guide_id : in_guide_id,
        week_start : in_week_start,
        week_end : in_week_end
    })
    .done(function (data) {

        var res_arr = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

        if (res_arr.code == 0) {
            this.excursions_base = res_arr.answer;
            alertify.success("Data extracted");
            this.createtimetable();
        } else {
            alertify.error("Some problem occured." + data);
        }
    }).fail(function () {
        alertify.alert("Error. Please, refresh page, or try later. We are sorry. Write or call us with your question!");
    });
}
```

Calling by name (i.e. createtimetable() ) also fail. Thank you for ideas!

Comment: `this` points to the context, so be careful about who and how is calling your functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store reference of `$(this)`outside of post function call ans use it in `done` callback function, here `this` doesn't refers to your object.

```
this.loadtimetable = function(in_guide_id, in_week_start, in_week_end)
{  
    var self = this; //store reference of this
    $.post( "./j.php", {})
      .done(function( data ) {
        self.createtimetable(); //Here instead of this use your variable
    });
}
```

### EDIT

If you are open to use `$.ajax()` instead of `$.post()`. You can use the [**context**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) option.

> This object will be made the context of all Ajax-related callbacks. By default, the context is an object that represents the ajax settings used in the call (`$.ajaxSettings` merged with the settings passed to `$.ajax`). *(...)*

```
$.ajax({
    context: this
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is executed in a callback, and `this` no longer points to your object. You should either use a closure, aliasing `this` to something like `self`, or explicitly bind this

```
this.createtimetable = function () {
    this.inside_timetable = [];
    for (var d = new Date(in_week_start); d <= new Date(in_week_end); d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {
        console.log(new Date(d));
        daysOfYear.push(new Date(d));
    }
}
this.loadtimetable = function (in_guide_id, in_week_start, in_week_end) {
    this.guide_id = in_guide_id;
    this.week_start = in_week_start;
    this.week_end = in_week_end;
    $.post("./j.php", {
        guide_id: in_guide_id,
        week_start: in_week_start,
        week_end: in_week_end
    })
    .done(function (data) {
        var res_arr = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        if (res_arr.code == 0) {
            this.excursions_base = res_arr.answer;
            alertify.success("Data extracted");
            this.createtimetable();
        } else {
            alertify.error("Some problem occured." + data);
        }
    }.bind(this)).fail(function () {
        alertify.alert("Error. Please, refresh page, or try later. We are sorry. Write or call us with your question!");
    }.bind(this));
}
```